# REGEX - Select multiple lines unless it finds the defined stop charecter

Tags: regex

I have a String

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
*consectetur adipiscing elit
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt*
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua
Ut enim ad minim veniam.
```

now I want to select the `* content *`

this `[*](.*?)[*]` is my current regex, but it's working with a single line

`*consectetur adipiscing elit*`

How do I make it multiline?

Comment: `[*]([\s\S]*?)[*]` ...

Comment: In which language are you coding?

Comment: @PierreFrançois Java (Android)

Comment: (.*?\n?) should work for line breaks.

Comment: @PranavCBalan ```[*]([\\s\\S]*?)[*]``` worked for me! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This REGEX worked for me `[*]([\\s\\S]*?)[*]`